# Задний фон для каждого пользователя свой

Tags: javascript, css

Допустим у каждого пользователя есть свойство задний фон. Мы храним путь к рисунку в переменной $userbg.
Как сделать, чтобы при заходе `site.ru/?name=user` у пользователя был задний фон?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<style>
body {
   background: url(/path/".$userbg.");
}
<style>";
```

Comment: А, пардон, это на php

Comment: javascript:  

    body.style.backgroundImage = $userbg;

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <script>
  var url=location.search;//получаем всё после знака ?
  url=url.split('=');//разбиваем строку
  var color=url[1];//узнаем цвет и дальше..
  if(color=='red') document.body.style.background='red';
  </script>
</body>
```

Советую усовершенствовать под ваши нужды, но вот основная идея
а вобще лучше б конечно с норм авторизацией и серверным языком вроде php..